# How to store form in order

Tags: 7, commerce

I have customers filling out an entry form before sending them to checkout.  Is it possible to store, or serialize, the $form_state array in the order?  There is a 'data' field in the order.  Is it simple as me calling:

```
$order->data = serialize($form_state);
commerce_order_save($order);
```

EDIT:

The data field in the order is an array that gets serialized.  So, it looks like I can do:

```
$order->data['myform'] = $form_state;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the `data` attribute on entities, which you cannot access through Entity Metadata Wrappers (per previous answer.)

Do you need the full form state or just values? Also, you do not need to serialize the data, as the entity controller will do this for you.

I would do something like:

```
form_state_values_clean($form_state);
$order->data['myform_values'] = $form_state['values'];
```

form_state_values_clean() will remove build IDs and such.

Comment: I didn't even know about the _clean() function.  Very cool. Thanks!

Comment: I've asked a related question about the $order->data property and where documentation for it can be found: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163176/where-is-documentation-for-entity-data-property-i-e-commerce-order-data

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a field to commerce_order called field_data and then save it, yes.

The pattern might be more like:

```
$order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_wrapper', $order_id);
$order_wrapper->field_data = serialize($form_state);
$order_wrapper->save();
```

Comment: There is already a data field in the order.  Am I not able to use that one?