# Where is documentation for $entity->data property? I.e. $commerce_order->data

Tags: entities, commerce

I've searched google and the Drupal API, but I can't seem to find documentation for the data array that serializes/unserializes automatically that is attached to entities and stored in the data column on some entities, particularly commerce_order. Searching for the world "data" is like searching for the word "the." Where/how is the data array serialized and unserialized?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a "requests for tutorials and other online resources", forbidden in [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Maybe it should be rephrased, then, to how the entity attribute 'data' is serialized and unserialized? Just wondering

Comment: Updated to reflect a question about how serialization/unserialization happens rather than a request for resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data attribute is part of the Commerce Entity definitions, and I think this might be part of the larger de facto Entity API setup for contrib entities (don't quote me on that ;).)

If you want to find the documentation on properties and how they are handled you need to review the EntityController class, which each Commerce module has in its includes folder.

[commerce_order.controller.inc#n135](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce/tree/modules/order/includes/commerce_order.controller.inc#n135)

```
/**
 * Unserializes the data property of loaded orders.
 */
public function attachLoad(&$queried_orders, $revision_id = FALSE) {
  foreach ($queried_orders as $order_id => &$order) {
    $order->data = unserialize($order->data);
}
```

The database layer automatically serializes, if I recall correctly. However controllers need to unserialize.

Hopefully this *this* question and other entity related items (also make sure to review hook_entity_info() implementation.)